# Anypoint CloudHub Deploy fails to update app

Tags: xml, maven, cloudhub

I set up a `mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS deploy -DmuleDeploy` job which consumes a pom.xml with the mule-maven-plugin 3.2.7 to deploy a Mule Runtime 4.2.1 app to a Development Sandbox.

The directions say to perform a `package deploy` but upon review that was causing double-duty and a very large JAR file.  157.2MB vs 52MB.  Regardless, I've tried it both ways and both fail in the same spot.

```
There were '5' errors while parsing the given file 'global.xml'.
Full list:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce/current/mule-salesforce.xsd; lineNumber: 781; columnNumber: 64; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'mule:abstract-transformer' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce/current/mule-salesforce.xsd; lineNumber: 781; columnNumber: 64; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'mule:abstractTransformerType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce/current/mule-salesforce.xsd; lineNumber: 790; columnNumber: 64; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'mule:abstract-transformer' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce/current/mule-salesforce.xsd; lineNumber: 790; columnNumber: 64; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'mule:abstractTransformerType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 133; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'salesforce:sfdc-config'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-on-error, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":top-level-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-object-store}' is expected.
```

XML File in question:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls"
    xmlns:salesforce="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce" xmlns:mule-aws-secrets-manager="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-aws-secrets-manager" xmlns:api-gateway="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/api-gateway" xmlns:secure-properties="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-properties" xmlns:json-logger="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json-logger" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:error-handler-plugin="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/error-handler-plugin" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/error-handler-plugin http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/error-handler-plugin/current/mule-error-handler-plugin.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json-logger http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json-logger/current/mule-json-logger.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-properties http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-properties/current/mule-secure-properties.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/api-gateway http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/api-gateway/current/mule-api-gateway.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-aws-secrets-manager http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-aws-secrets-manager/current/mule-mule-aws-secrets-manager.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce/current/mule-salesforce.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd">
    <secure-properties:config name="Secure_Properties_Config" doc:name="Secure Properties Config" doc:id="df66b474-5f03-4b58-ba1f-4627d15b998b" file="env-config.properties" key="${mule.key}" >
    </secure-properties:config>
    <configuration-properties doc:name="Configuration properties" doc:id="9ace4937-53e9-4026-9e93-feb4edb03362" file="common.properties" />
    <http:listener-config name="api-template-api-httpListenerConfig">
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="${listener.port}">
        </http:listener-connection>
    </http:listener-config>
    <apikit:config name="api-config" raml="api.raml" outboundHeadersMapName="outboundHeaders" httpStatusVarName="httpStatus" />
    <json-logger:config name="JSON_Logger_Config" doc:name="JSON Logger Config" doc:id="bf1bc03f-3b97-4896-8aa6-18404829e5dc" disabledFields="${json.logger.disabled.fields}" applicationName="${json.logger.application.name}" applicationVersion="${json.logger.application.version}"/>
    <api-gateway:autodiscovery apiId="${secure::api.id}" doc:name="API Autodiscovery" doc:id="424ac292-35fb-4809-85b0-e4c29d7999bc" flowRef="api-template-api-main" />
<!--    <salesforce:sfdc-config name="Salesforce_Config_Final" doc:name="Salesforce Config" doc:id="a4c56d4f-e618-4126-ad9b-59bc4d3ff967" > -->
<!--        <salesforce:cached-oauth-jwt-connection consumerKey="${secure::consumer.key}" keyStore="${secure::keystore.path}" storePassword="${secure::keystore.password}" principal="${secure::principal.user}" tokenEndpoint="${secure::token.endpoint}" /> -->
<!--    </salesforce:sfdc-config> -->
    <salesforce:sfdc-config name="Salesforce_Config_Final" doc:name="Salesforce Config" doc:id="cddc726d-430e-44d2-b9d8-6a44109d8957" >
        <salesforce:cached-basic-connection username="${secure::salesforce.user}" password="${secure::salesforce.password}" url="${secure::salesforce.url}" securityToken="${secure::salesforce.token}"/>
    </salesforce:sfdc-config>

</mule>
```

I do not know if this is a sign its missing a `${parameter.name}` or if a developer truly created a invalid XML structure within the `src/main/mule/global.xml`.

I did structure the pom to include this for the mule-maven-plugin:

```xml
<cloudHubDeployment>
    <server>anypoint-exchange</server>
    <uri>https://anypoint.mulesoft.com</uri>
    <businessGroupId>${project.groupId}</businessGroupId>
    <environment>${env.CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}</environment>
    <muleVersion>${app.runtime}</muleVersion>
    <applicationName>${env.LAB}-${project.artifactId}</applicationName>
    <properties>
        <!-- Place App Properties here -->
        <!--Salesforce Credentials-->
        <salesforce.user>${env.SALESFORCE_USER}</salesforce.user>
        <salesforce.password>${env.SALESFORCE_PASS}</salesforce.password>
        <salesforce.token>${env.SALESFORCE_TOKEN}</salesforce.token>
        <salesforce.url>${env.SALESFORCE_URL}</salesforce.url>
        <!--Salesforce Account Object-->
        <account.recordTypeId>${env.ACCOUNT_RECORDTYPEID}</account.recordTypeId>
        <mule.key>${env.MULE_KEY}</mule.key>
        <!--app.id>${env.APP_ID}</app.id-->
    </properties>
    <region>${env.ANYPOINT_REGION}</region>
    <workers>${env.ANYPOINT_WORKERS}</workers>
    <workerType>${env.ANYPOINT_WORKERTYPE}</workerType>
    <!--artifact>path/to/file</artifact-->
</cloudHubDeployment>
```

I also notice in the app it deploys under Runtime Manager and properties that it only lists the mule.key, not any of the other parameters.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is no context in the log snippet to understand if it is happening in the deployed app -ie it showing those errors in CloudHub- or if it happening in the Maven log, which would mean it is happening when running the test phase (Munit).
More lines around the errors would also be good.

Comment: XML Errors are occurring in the Runtime Manager after deployment as its spinning up.  Dev's currently have no unit tests to run.

Answer (score 0):

Tip for anyone running into this issue.  It is a sign you're missing dependencies in your project.  This was a situation where I had code zipped and delivered that didn't match the original jar deployed.  I had to unzip the jar, and compare pom files.  Turns out a couple dependencies were missing:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-salesforce-connector</artifactId>
    <version>9.7.9</version>
    <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-scripting-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
    <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
</dependency>
```

That got the app working again.  I was mainly shocked this didn't get picked up by the verify/validate type process but no unit tests were written and you don't run into these org.xml.sax.SAXparseExceptions until the jar is deployed.

Thanks